# Criar planilhas com Django

Tags: python, django

Olá,
Estou implementando um botão para transformar uma Query em uma planilha e disponibilizar esse download.
Para isso criei uma View para gerar o Excel, segue:

```
def export_view_csv(request):
    if request == 'POST':
        dados = request.POST.get('csv_sender')
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Consulta' + str(datetime.now()) + '.csv'

        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12'])

        for info in dados:
            writer.writerow(
                [info['nomefa'], info['razaos'], info['cnpj'], info['uf'], info['situac'], info['porte'], info['lograd'],
                 info['numero'],
                 info['comple'], info['muibge'], info['dsituc'], info['capsoc']])

    return response
```

e criei o formulário enviando para essa view o campo escondido, segue forms:

```
<form method="POST" action = "{% url 'core:csv-export' %}">
      <div class="module-option clearfix">
           <div class="input-append pull-left">
                <input type="hidden" name="csv_sender" value="{{ results }}"/>
                {% csrf_token %}
                 <button type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">
                         <a>Baixar Planilha</a>
                 </button>
           </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Mas estou enfrentando o seguinte erro e não sei como proceder:

```
AttributeError at /csv-export/
'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

    path('mylogout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='mylogout'),
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('contato/', contato_email, name='contato'),
    path('csv-export/', export_view_csv, name='csv-export'),
]
```

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz...

Comment: Coloca o `urls.py` no seu post também.

Comment: Claro, colocado!

Comment: Desculpe perguntar em doses homeopáticas, pode colocar a view que chama o form?

Comment: É o primeiro código do post pelo que entendi sua pergunta

Comment: Então, vc não possui outra view relacionada a este processo de gerar e fazer download?

Comment: A variável `request` está chegando na sua _view_ como uma string e não como o objeto contendo a requisição HTTP vinda do navegador (tanto que a validação `request == "POST"` está funcionando, pois deveria ser `request.method == "POST"`).

Comment: Obrigado Giovanni, era exatamente este o meu Problema. Consegui resolver agradeço pela ajuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que ficaria mais fácil trabalhar com mais de uma view, utilizando o MEDIA_URL para salvar um arquivo temporário.

O fluxo seria acessar a view que gera os dados e esta redirecionar para a view que permitiria o download.

## Views

### Primeira view - acessa_dados

```
def buscar_dados(param1, param2...):
    # busca os dados
    # salva os dados
    # algo como: ???.save(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_name))
    return file_name  # inclui o /path/to/file/arquivo.xlsx


def acessa_dados(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyQueryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            resultado = busca_dados(passar parametros aqui>)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('minha_app:get_file', args=[resultado]))
    else:
        form = MyQueryForm()
    return render(request, 'acessa_dados_form.html', {'form': form})
```

### Segunda view - get_file

```
def get_file(request, file_path):
    return render(request, 'get_file.html', context={'file_path': f'/media/{file_path}'})


def download(request, file_path):
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

### Url.py

```
app_name = 'minha_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', acessa_dados, name='acessa'),
    path('get_file/<str:file_path>', get_file, name='get_file'),
    path('download/<str:file_path>', download, name='download'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,  document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Em tempo: get_file.html é somente um link de download do arquivo.

Espero ter ajudado